# Unhandled exception in clEnqueueReadBuffer on Intel CPU

Tags: windows, opencl, intel

I get "Unhandled exception at 0x770915de in irena.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x08bd1000." message when running my application on Intel's CPU using OpenCL on Windows. Exception is thrown in clEnqueueReadBuffer function.
When I use NVIDIA's GPU (both on Windows and Linux) there is everything OK so I guess that my code works fine.

Does anybody have any idea what couses this exception is thrown ?

I have i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz, Windows 7 and I am using x86 OpenCL.lib form Intel's SDK v3.0.

Comment: You are probably trying to read from out of bounds.

Comment: That was it. Thanks ! I do not understand why there was everything ok on NVIDIA's GPU.

Comment: I am speculating here, but NVIDIA may be a bit more lax with out of bound accesses.